# Проблема с фоновым запуском процесса PHP

Tags: php, yii2

Запускаю фоновый процесс так:

```
$command = "php -d max_execution_time=3600 -f /var/www/shop/application/yii multi-create-product/run " . $file_name . " >/dev/null &";
exec($command);
```

В коде есть строчка file_put_contents( $this->path_file, $output ); и скрипт виснет на ней. Просто виснет - ни ошибки ни чего. Папка есть - куда файл будет писаться. Права полные.

Если запустить скрипт в консоле - ручками - то все нормально - скрипт проходит нормально и файл записывается.

Comment: exec функция случайно не выключена?

Comment: Когда я закомментил строчку с выводом в файл - то все норм работает. Там основная работа идет с БД, а в файл лог валится.

Comment: Проверьте имя файла - если оно содержит пробелы - заключите его в двойные кавычки

Comment: Нет - пробелов нет

Comment: Тогда нужно смотреть, что Вы внутри `MultiCreateProductController` в `actionRun` присваиваете в `$this->path_file`